# R - NAs turn columns into character class (should be integer/ numeric)

Tags: r

I imported a huge dataset with a lot of missing values or N/As, NAs.

This is how i import the Data:

```
Databsp<-read.csv("C:/Users/adminfor/Desktop/Neuer Ordner/Pseudonymized-Genet-Treatment-Summary-20220201120538.csv", na.strings=TRUE)
```

Next, I converedt all the NAs or N/As to using the following code:

```
a <- Databsp %>% replace_with_na_all(condition = ~.x %in% common_na_strings)
```

Now my question: Why are columns that only include numbers and NAs from the class "character" and not "integer/numeric". I tried several codes, but nothing seems to help...

Comment: I've edited your question to include code formatting. Please don't undo the edits again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change your column classes. When you import your data, the column classes are first set, and you do nothing to change them. If a column in your CSV file has only numeric and `NA` values when you import it, it will be numeric. But if it has strings (including strings that you haven't yet told R are NA-equivalent, like `"N/A"`) then `read.csv` must read them as `character` class because they are not numeric. Later, you replace those NA-equivalent values with actual `NA`s, but that replaces values only, it does not change the class of the columns.

The bad solution would be to patch this. Add an extra step after you replace the NA values, you could use the `type.convert()` function to re-assess the columns and convert them as necessary, `a <- type.convert(a)`.

The better solution is to give `read.csv` your list of NA-equivalent strings when you read in the data. This is what the `na.strings` argument is supposed to be. From `?read.csv`

> `na.strings`
> a character vector of strings which are to be interpreted as `NA` values.

So change your import line to

```
Databsp <- read.csv(
  "C:/Users/adminfor/Desktop/Neuer Ordner/Pseudonymized-Genet-Treatment-Summary-20220201120538.csv",
   na.strings = common_na_strings
)
```

And then the columns should be classed appropriately when you read them in, and you can skip the `replace_with_na_all` step as it is already taken care of. Relatedly, your current `na.strings = TRUE` does nothing because `TRUE` is not a character vector.

Comment: Thank you! The  "na.strings = common_na_strings" step did the job perfectly!